# How many matrices satisfies the following conditions?

Tags: matrices, permutations, integers

Suppose a matrix  $X \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ with its entries being $\{ 0,1,2,\cdots \}$. The imposed conditions are
\begin{align}
\sum_i {X_{i,j}}=n_j, \forall j \\
\sum_j {X_{i,j}}=m_i, \forall i
\end{align}
where $m_i$ and $n_j$ are predefined variables. My question is how many matrices $X$ satisfy the conditions above? Any idea is appriciated. Thank!

Comment: Of course for a solution to exist you need $\sum_j n_j = \sum_i m_i$.  This condition turns out to be necessary and sufficient.  But I don't think the number of solutions is easy to compute.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The condition you mentioned is required for the problem.